GPS Map Camera app with automatic upload to database
I want to an app that has features available in GPS Map Camera app (gpsmapcamera.com).
I want to an app that has features available in GPS Map Camera app (gpsmapcamera.com). Apart from that, once the user takes a photo with this app, the app should record location data such as area name, postal code, city name, state name and country name in database in searchable form. These images should be stored in publicly accessible database with an option of sharing the image on social media.
Please tell me if anyone can build this app for me.
